# There is no build provider registered for the extension '.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net, csproj

I'm trying to reference to a .dll file from a .aspx web page.  However, I get the following error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: There is no build provider registered for the extension '.dll'. You can register one in the <compilation><buildProviders> section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

Source Error: 

Line 2:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"   MasterPageFile="CSharpBPTestMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CSharpBPTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Button"  Debug="true"%>  
Line 3:  
Line 4:  <%@ Register tagprefix="blnc" tagname="Balanced" src="bin/Debug/BalancedTest.dll" %>
Line 5:  
Line 6:

Source File: /preview/1/balanced-csharp-master/src/BalancedTest/CSharpBPTest.aspx    Line: 4
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I build the .csproj file.  I have the following in `bin\Debug\`:

- Balanced.dll
- Balanced.pdb
- BalancedTest.dll
- BalancedTest.pdb

Here is my `CSharpBPTest.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"   MasterPageFile="CSharpBPTestMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CSharpBPTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Button"  Debug="true"%>   

<%@ Register tagprefix="blnc" tagname="Balanced" src="bin/Debug/BalancedTest.dll" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
    Runat="Server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


    <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button_Command"/>

    <br />


    <br />
            <br><asp:label id="warningLabel" Text="" ForeColor="Red" runat="server"/><br>
    <br />  


    </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

And in my C# file, I "import" the project like this (at the top):

```
using Balanced;
```

I want to be able to use this compiled .dll file on my C# side.  The Balanced.dll is an external library.  It just came with the files and a .csproj file.  I did a build and now I'm trying to use this Balanced.dll file.  Am I missing something?  I'm sorry if this is a bad question.  I'm new to asp.net and csproj.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You need to specify the namespace, not the src.  src is for usercontrols/servercontrols within the project.

Your namespace value will depend on how the DLL was compiled and its namespaces are structured.

Also, you do not specify the tagName in this case.  The tagName will be the DLL control's class name.

A very basic example is:

```
<%-- assumes that 'BalancedTest' is the namespace that this control is in, and that the BalancedTest.dll already has a class that inherits UserControl (or a child of it) with the name 'BalancedTest'. --%>
<%@ Register tagprefix="blnc" Namespace="BalancedTest" %>
```

Comment: Now it says in the C# file:   Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Balanced' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The DLL must be in your bin folder (which it looks like it's already there), but you must also add a reference to your project.  Right click the solution in solution explorer and choose 'add reference.'  Click on 'browse' and search for the dll within your project files.  Click add or check the box to include the reference.  This process has changed a bit between previous Visual Studios and 2012, so you'll have to tell me what version you have for further assistance, or google how to add a reference.

Comment: I actually use Web Expressions instead of Visual Studios.  Does it work the same?  I'm using a .csproj file that came with an external library (written by someone else).  I'm trying to use that library (in format of a .dll) with just 3 files (.cs, .aspx, and .master).

Comment: I meant Expressions Web*

Comment: I got Visual Studio and used that to add the reference.  However, it says the reference is already there.  Then it still gives me the compilation issue when I put the code on my server.

Comment: Are you putting the dll in the /bin/ folder?  I just noticed your original src attribute pointed to a /debug/bin folder, which is incorrect: `bin/Debug/BalancedTest.dll`.  The DLL should just be in the regular /bin/ folder; Visual Studio will copy it to /debug/ or /release/ where necessary when building the solution.  Double check the ASP.NET version IIS is using on the server.  Sometimes it defaults to 2.0 when it should be something else.  Look at your solution's properties by right-clicking it in solution explorer and selecting 'Properties.'  There should be a 'Target Framework' option.

Comment: Set IIS to use a compatible version of .NET for your site.